# using application.properties value in resources / logback-spring.xml

Tags: xml, spring-boot

i want to Use spring boot's application.properties value in resources/logback-spring.xml.

But do not use it like this:
application.properties

```
server.kafka.host0=kafka-0
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<producerConfig>bootstrap.servers=${server.kafka.host0}:9092</producerConfig>
```

How can I write? Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by using `<springProperty>` tag as stated in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_environment_properties)

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="kafkaHost0" source="server.kafka.host0"/>
<producerConfig>bootstrap.servers=${kafkaHost0}:9092</producerConfig>
```